# Как отлепить картинку от левого края?

Tags: веб-программирование, теги

Делаю сайт: http://rusafaga.ru/test/index3.htm

При просмотре на смартфоне картинки отображаются по центру. Когда смотрим на компьютере, уменьшив размер окна браузера до мобильного устройства, картинка прилипает к левому краю. Вроде везде align выставил как надо. Может какой другой тег нужно? Или ошибка где-то...

Comment: @KAGGDesign Правка была совсем неверной?

Comment: @0xdb Что-то я уже запутался, получается на ресурсе у всех свои правила редактирования. Смотрю как кто делает, у многих серьезно все отличается. Читал рулсы, что-то у каждого тут свое...Беда.

Comment: @VladSpirin Ну да, я тоже пытаюсь попасть в струю, но струя каждый день меняет направление.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178988

Comment: @0xdb похоже, мы одновременно редактировали этот вопрос. А с телефона в приложении вообще никакая история правок не видна...

Comment: @0xdb да, смотрю историю правок, и вижу, что я редактировал исходный вопрос. Ваши правки я бы не стал возвращать назад.

Comment: @0xdb объединил наши правки. Я-то правил, в первую очередь, орфографию.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Хорошо оставим так. Странно, что правки не смержились. А после вашей правки у меня окно в броузере почему то обновилось похоронив начатый комментарий. С телефона я приложение убрал потому, что оно глючит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там все слишком просто, уберите у .left & .right - text-align: center, а родителю дайте

Comment: Спасибо! Все исправил! =)

Comment: Тогда отметьте мой вопрос решением, если он вам помог

Comment: Простите, я впервые здесь. Зеленую галочку поставил слева от вашего ответа. Правильно? И не вижу никакой кнопки "вопрос решен" или "закрыть обсуждение"... Или это не нужно?

Comment: Извините, опять проблема вернулась. Предыдущий способ с gif анимацией не подошел. Пришлось переделать с mp4 и добавить позиционирование, чтобы скрыть видео до наведения на него мышкой. Теперь картинка липнет влево на смартфоне.

Comment: Да, галочка - это решение, благодарю. Странно, у меня сейчас нормально, все отцентрировано, скорее вы решили уже эту проблему, или нет?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению. На компьютере в обоих режимах отцентровано, а на смартфоне в хроме картинка слева висит...

Comment: Вы дали div'y  align="center", в котором находится видео, напомню, у родителя уже стоит это свойство, то есть дочерние элементы принимают его от родительского блока, поэтому align="center" не нужен, может из-за него ломается, в прошлый раз было из-за этого, если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: И, еще советую убрать абсолютное позиционирование <video>, так как у картинки есть это позиционирование. Советую сделать mp4 в gif, затем добавить hover при наведении на картинку, и, меняйте background-image